# Can't find host.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created a new azure function, and I have a step to read host.json, it worked on my desk, but when I publish to Azure, I got an error:

> The configuration file 'host.json' was not found and is not optional.
>   The physical path is 'D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12507\32bit\host.json'.

Here what I tried:

```
var Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                          .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                          .AddJsonFile("host.json",false)
                          .Build();

var value = Configuration["value"];
```

So how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Volodymyr mentioned, you need to **pass the ExecutionContext** within your Azure Function method:.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run( ... , ExecutionContext context) 
{
    ...
}
```

Now when you build your configuration, you set the base path using the `ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory` property. I also optional add the local.settings.json for local debug purpose:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory) // Here you include the app directory from the context
    .AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true) 
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true) // for local debugging
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

---

To further improve your code I would recommend *creating a class for your Settings*. For example:

```
public sealed class FunctionSettings
{
    public string MySetting { get; set; } 
}
```

This way you can access the settings like this:

```
var settings = new FunctionSettings();
config.Bind(settings);

var value = settings.MySetting
```

instead of

```
var value = Configuration["MySetting"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ExecutionContext](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function#net-languages-c-f-etc)  it has property `FunctionAppDirectory`